# Will WAMP run on Windows 2008 Foundation?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to run WAMP on a 2008 server and need to specify requirements for a customer. Am trying to get away with as little as possible Windows wise, and obviously don't need IIS.

Comment: Just curious, what do you want to run that *needs* windows, yet runs on a amp stack?

Comment: there are elements of my solution that require ODBC connectivity and the drivers I need for this are Windows-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run, but be aware of the single proc / 8 GB limitation!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking but yes, it is possible to install WAMP on Windows Server 2008

Comment: there are multiple version of Windows 2008 server, one of which is called "Foundations." It is substantially less $$ for purchase, especially OEM. I'm just looking to verify whether it's crippled in anyway if I want to put Apache, MySQL and PHP on it.

Comment: In that regard you should be fine. Microsoft charges more for their proprietary software. Since you don't need any of that I see no reason as to why it wouldn't work. I don't know your specific needs but you could probably get away with Windows 7 or even LAMP (linux).